# node js express - middleware next() is not triggering consecutive fm in mocha test cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, middleware

I have configured a middleware (router level) which checks for admin access, and if successful I am logging the information and calling `next()`.

**middleware:**

```
const validateAdmin = function (scope) {
        return function (req, res, next) {
            
            if (req.admin) {
                //log the information and using scope to log 
                next();
            } else {
                
                // send the response with 403
            }
        };
    };
```

**router level usage**

```
router.use('/rule/:name', validateAdmin({ serviceScope: this.#serviceScope }), async (req, res) => {
    await this._handleRequest(req, res);
});
```

**working case**

when i trigger the req from postman, i can see that middleware is called and after next getting executed, the control is coming to 'await this._handleRequest(req, res);' which is expected.

**issue**

Test case

```
it.only('shall get single rule', async function () {
        
    const getSingleReq = {
        method: 'GET',
        admin: true,
        originalUrl: '<some req>/rule/rule_1',
        baseUrl: '<some_req>',
        query: {},
        params: { name: 'rule_1' },
        headers: {
            //token info
        },
        body: {}
    };

    const next = sinon.spy();
    await router.use.args[1][1](getSingleReq, res, next);
}));
```

when `await router.use.args[1][1](getSingleReq, res, next);` is called, I can see the middleware is triggered but `next()` is not calling the subsequent middleware. I expect that `await this._handleRequest(req, res);` is called just like the scenario when triggered from postman.

I hope the issue is clear.

Referred many use cases but everywhere the scenario of just checking if next() is called is only done .